# How to compare an input value with value in table with React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an amount in my table and I want the amount entered by user not be superior of 90% of the amount of the table. How can I do this?

How can I get just the value of amount in controller with JavaScript?

```
handleChange(event){
    let soldeCompte;

    if(name=="montant"){
          soldeCompte=event.target.childNodes[event.target.selectedIndex].getAttribute('montant');
          this.setState({
              maxMontant:montant*0.01>400000?400000:90*montant*0.01
          })
    };
  }
```

They give that `montant` is not defined.

Comment: Welcome to SO! A couple things to keep in mind when asking questions. Java != JavaScript, you can indent your code 4 spaces to make it a block (or use fencing backticks (```) around it), and there's no need to put quotes around your title--that's just how the example is formatted.

Comment: `montant` is not defined.  Can you show us in your code where that variable is declared?  And what are you doing with `soldeCompte`? It doesn't look like you're using it anywhere.

Comment: i use it here:<Label for="exampleNumber">Montant</Label>
                  <Input
                    type="number" name="montant" value={this.state.newavanceData.montant} onChange={this.handlechange} => {
                      let { newavanceData } = this.state;
        
                      newavanceData.montant = e.target.value;
        
                      this.setState({ newavanceData });
                    }} />

Comment: soldecompte is a variable

Comment: How is the amount in the table being set?

Comment: i don't understund you